# Object not found when getting Qlik object by id

Tags: qliksense

I am getting error when trying to get the object.  I am trying to retrieve the table whose id is "hJdkLkt" based on what i see in the dev hub. I can see that it's creating the session but i am not getting anything.

```
this.session = enigma.create({
  schema,
  url: 'ws://localhost:9076/app/sampleApp'
});
this.session.open()
  .then(global => global.createSessionApp())
  .then(doc => doc.getObject('hJdkLkt').then(obj => console.log(obj)))
  .then(() => this.session.close())
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: You are creating an empty session app. There are no objects there yet. In order to get object you need to connect to an existing app with objects in it

Comment: Yes, i understand now.  It's actually difficult to follow the documentation. I had to go through the API to understand

Comment: Yea you need a momment of "mental switch" but in general the logic is: connect to the engine (open session), open an app, get objects

Comment: i was able to get the table object through openDoc, then getObject, then getLayout, then i getHyperCubeData... i was able to get the data from the table, however, i need only a subset of data (for example, those records whose column1 value equals "YES").  Do you know where I can set this selection filter?